# How do I find the ID of an existing widget in WordPress? I need to run a function only when the widget appears on the front end

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, hook

Here is the hook that I'm using:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', function (){ //Run only if TablePress is active in the current page.
    if (is_active_widget(false, false, $this->id_base, true)){
        add_action('wp_footer', 'mhsTableMakePhoneNumbersClickable');
    }
});
```

I want `mhsTableMakePhoneNumbersClickable()` to only run when there is a Table Press table in the front end. But I have no idea what the ID for Table Press would even look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ID of a widget using Inspect tool on your browser.  If you inspect the widget, it will usually show something like "Text-8" or something like that.

Alternatively, you could add this to functions.php or a plugin, and it should display the widget ID on the actual widget in the Appearance->Widgets area.  Keep in mind the widget must be saved before the ID will be shown.

```
add_action('in_widget_form', 'show_widget_id');

function show_widget_id($widget_instance)

{
   echo "<p><strong>Widget ID: </strong>" .$widget_instance->id. "</p>"; 
}
```